# one to many relationships in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Each industry has many projects
each project belongs to only one industry

industries table has columns as below:

`id, industry_name, industry_code, created_at, updated_at`

projects table has columns as below:

`id, industry_id (foreign key), user_id, project_name, project_start_date, project_end_date, created_at, updated_at`

I want to show project name and industry name in my `index.blade.php` (view)

I have created Project & Industry models. How do I show the result in my view?

```
Industry.php model:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Industry extends Model
{
    public function project()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Project');
    }
}

Project.php model:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model 
{
    public function industry()
    {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Industry');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this ...

```
$Industry = App\Industry ::find(1);

echo $Industry ->Project ->project_name;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: do I put this in my controller or my view? 
also, do I need to do a foreach loop?

Comment: get data in controller and pass it to view..yes.. if you have more then one industry in return data u need to do a foreach loop ... check laravel documentaion for more.

Answer (score 0):

do try renaming your method "project" to "projects" in Industry.php since it is a "hasMany" relationship. this would prevent you from making errors.

in your controller, say PagesController.php

```
public function index() {
   // find an industry with id of 1
   $Industry = App\Industry ::find(1);
   return view('some_view',compact('industry'));

}
```

therefore in your view, since an industry has many projects you can access them and loop over them by `$Industry->projects`. However you should consider eager loading them in order to prevent the n + 1 problem. there edit your query to `$Industry = App\Industry ::with('projects')->find(1);`

read more on eager loading https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

If specifically you want only project_name and industry_name then
try this -

```
$result = App\Industry::with(array('projects'=> function($query){
                                 $query->addSelect(['project_name']);
                       }))
                      ->where('industry.id',$id)
                      ->get([industry_name]);
```

else for all records try this -

```
$result = App\Industry::with('projects')
                      ->where('industry.id',$id)
                      ->get();
```

Hope this will help you.